# How to print a matrix with a certain pattern in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, square

How can we create a pattern using Python which will create a square Matrix it will put values of diagonal elements equal to zero change the value of elements above diagonal elements 29 and change the values below that a diagonal equals to 5.

For example:

```
Input: 4

Output:

0999
5099
5509
5550
```

Please Help. Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried printing pattern like using loop but that didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just have to print, you can try following

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        # diagonal case
        if i == j:
            print(0, end='')
        # upper diagonal case
        elif i < j:
            print(9, end='')
        # lower diagonal case
        else:
            print(5, end='')
    print('')
```

Comment: Instead of `print('')` we can just use `print()` (or `print` in Python 2) without any arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `numpy` library.

```py
import numpy as np

np.identity(4) # This will print out 1 on the diagnoals and 0 on the rest.
```

After that just use a loop to change all the 1s (diagnoals) to 0s
Then use if statements and loops to identify whether a number is above the 0 or not

Or if you just want to use a matrix with a predefined list, then just use `np.array(list)`

Comment: But how can print as I said others number like 9s in upper portion and 5s in lower

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the condition for , diagonal (row_index == column_index), upper triangular matrix (column_index > row_index) and lower_triangular matrix (row_index > column_index) and then add values accordingly

```
def func(n):
    l = []
    for i in range(n):
        tmp = []
        for j in range(n):
            if j==i:
                tmp.append(0)
            elif j>i:
                tmp.append(9)
            elif j<n:
                tmp.append(5)
        l.append(tmp)
    return l
```

Answer (score 1):

The key phrases to search for are "upper triangle" and "lower triangle". Once that's done, we can compose the desired output like this:

```
import numpy as np

shape = (4, 4)
np.tril(np.full(shape, 5), -1) + np.triu(np.full(shape, 9), 1)
```

How this works:

- `np.full(shape, fill_value)` constructs an array of the given shape, filled with the given number.
- `np.tril(m, k)` returns the lower triangle of the matrix `m`, from the `k`th diagonal (with the rest zeroed).
- Similarly, `np.triu(m, k)` returns the upper triangle of the matrix `m`, from the `k`th diagonal (with the rest zeroed).

Comment: What is (np) ??

Comment: Ah, `import numpy as np`; I'll add that to the answer...

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick

```
def pattern(size):
    for i in range(size):
        print('5'*i + '0' + '9'*(size-i-1))
        
pattern(4)
```